# How to replace limited number of occurrences in string

Tags: swift

Let's say that I have the string `"blabla[R]bla[R]blaaa[R]blabla[R]bla[R]bla"`.

The regular `replacingOccurrences` replaces all occurrences. I want to replace only 3.

```
newString = myString.replacingOccurrences(of: "[R]", with: "(X)")
```

to make the result `"blabla(X)bla(X)blaaa(X)blabla[R]bla[R]bla"`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the first 3 ranges occurrences of that string and then you can iterate the ranges in reverse order replacing the subranges:

```
var string = "blabla[R]bla[R]blaaa[R]blabla[R]bla[R]bla"
var ranges: [Range<String.Index>] = []
var start = string.startIndex
while start < string.endIndex, 
    let range = string.range(of: "[R]", range: start..<string.endIndex) {
    ranges.append(range)
    start = range.upperBound
    if ranges.count == 3 { break }
}

for range in ranges.reversed() {
    string.replaceSubrange(range, with:  "(X)")
}
print(string)  // blabla(X)bla(X)blaaa(X)blabla[R]bla[R]bla
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a useful extension to String that add a `count` parameter to `replacingOccurrences`. This includes support for ranges and options (such as backwards).

```
extension String {
    func replacingOccurrences<Target, Replacement>(of target: Target, with replacement: Replacement, count: Int, options: String.CompareOptions = [], range searchRange: Range<String.Index>? = nil) -> String where Target : StringProtocol, Replacement : StringProtocol {
        var matches = [Range<String.Index>]()
        var sRange = searchRange ?? Range(startIndex..<endIndex)
        while matches.count < count && !sRange.isEmpty {
            if let mRange = range(of: target, options: options, range: sRange, locale: nil) {
                matches.append(mRange)
                if options.contains(.backwards) {
                    sRange = Range(sRange.lowerBound..<mRange.lowerBound)
                } else {
                    sRange = Range(mRange.upperBound..<sRange.upperBound)
                }
            } else {
                break
            }
        }

        var res = self
        for range in matches.sorted(by: { $0.lowerBound > $1.lowerBound }) {
            res.replaceSubrange(range, with: replacement)
        }
        return res
    }
}

let test = "blabla[R]bla[R]blaaa[R]blabla[R]bla[R]bla"
let res1 = test.replacingOccurrences(of: "[R]", with: "(x)", count: 3)
print(res1)
let res2 = test.replacingOccurrences(of: "[R]", with: "(x)", count: 3, options: [ .backwards ])
print(res2)
```

Output:

> blabla(x)bla(x)blaaa(x)blabla[R]bla[R]bla
>   blabla[R]bla[R]blaaa(x)blabla(x)bla(x)bla

Comment: `var sRange = searchRange ?? startIndex..<endIndex
        while matches.count < count && !sRange.isEmpty {
            if let mRange = range(of: target, options: options, range: sRange) {
                matches.append(mRange)
                sRange = options.contains(.backwards) ?
                    sRange.lowerBound..<mRange.lowerBound :
                    mRange.upperBound..<sRange.upperBound
            } else {
                break
            }
        }`

Comment: btw specifying `String.Index` inside a String extension is redundant. `var matches = [Range<Index>]()` the same applies to `options: String.CompareOptions` can also be written as  `options: CompareOptions`