# replacing string value at index swift

Tags: ios, swift, string

I am trying to add a remove a the first character of a string got from a text input and replace it with another character but the new string replaces every value that has `0` instead of just the initial number. below is the code that I have tried

```
let swiftyString = phoneNumberField.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: "0", with: "44")
        print("STRING \(swiftyString!)")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
let res =  "44\(swiftyString.dropFirst())"
```

Or create

```
extension String {

    mutating func replaceFirst(_ str:String)  {

        self =  str + self.dropFirst()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `insert(_,at:)` instead of `replacingOccurrences`

```
if var phone = phoneNumberField.text?.dropFirst() {
    phone.insert("44", at: phone.startIndex)
}
```

**To replace N-th character:**

```
extension String {
    func replace(_ with: String, at index: Int) -> String {
        var modifiedString = String()
        for (i, char) in self.enumerated() {
            modifiedString += String((i == index) ? with : String(char))
        }
        return modifiedString
    }
}
```

**Use:**

```
let string = "wqrtyry"
let dd = string.replace("R", at: 2)
print(dd)
```

Answer (score 3):

In case if you want to replace the first character:

```
guard let input = phoneNumberField.text as? String{
       return
}
let outPut = "44" + String(input.dropFirst())
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `regularExpression` option, the leading caret (`^`) considers only the beginning of the string

```
let swiftyString = phoneNumberField.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: "^0", with: "44", options: .regularExpression)
```

---

Or `replaceSubrange` in an extension

```
extension String {
    mutating func replaceLeadingZero(with string: String) {
        if hasPrefix("0") { replaceSubrange(...startIndex, with: string) }
    }
}

let swiftyString = phoneNumberField.text?.replaceLeadingZero(with: "44")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're feeling a little adventurous then you can use the code below

```
    var string = "05942208638"
    var ranges: [Range<String.Index>] = []
    var start = string.startIndex
    while start < string.endIndex,
        let range = string.range(of: "0", range: start..<string.endIndex) {
            ranges.append(range)
            start = range.upperBound
            if ranges.count == 1 { break }
    }

    for range in ranges.reversed() {
        string.replaceSubrange(range, with:  "44")
    }
    print(string)  //prints 445942208638
```

Inspired from https://stackoverflow.com/a/50992959/5324042

Answer (score 1):

let swiftyString =  "44" + phoneNumberField.text?.dropFirst()